# Hi there I want to write a program in kotlin that receives a string from user and prints last two elements of that string twice

Tags: kotlin

val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)

```
println("Enter word: ")
var word = scan.next()

var a = word.length-1
var b = word.length-2

//var str = word.substring(b, a)
var str = word.length
word.get(b++)
word.get(a++)

print(word.get(b))
print(word.get(a))
```

Comment: Welcome, So what's the problem here?

Comment: I want to write a program in kotlin that receives a string from user and prints last two elements of that string twice

Comment: but as u see my code is completely mess)))

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin `in` is a keyword and needs to be put in backtics for variables with that name. so you could replace

```
val scan = Scanner(System.in)
```

with

```
val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
```

However, there's actually no need to make a scanner. Kotlin has the build in function `readln` to read the input.

furthermore, these line don't do anything useful

```
word.get(b++)
word.get(a++)
```

and it actually will bring `a` outside the range of the word.

also it looks nicer to write `word[a]` instead of `word.get(a)`. They do exactly the same

It's also recommended to use `val` instead of `var` if you're not changing the value aftwards

So I believe this is what you would like:

```
println("Enter word: ")
val word = readln()

val a = word.length-1
val b = word.length-2

print(word[b])
print(word[a])

print(word[b])
print(word[a])
```